# Проблема с библиотеками в Alt Linux

Tags: linux, qt

У меня имеется проект написанный на `Qt` версии `5.13` и с библиотеками соответствующей версии. На `Alt Linux` есть библиотеки версии `5.12.6`. Я добавил путь со своими библиотеками в `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` .Но приложение все равно тянет библиотеки версии `5.12.6`(файл `libQt5Core.so.5`),а после удаления этой либры приложения стало тянуть нужную либру. Подскажите как решить данную ситуацию?

Comment: А тулчейн в креаторе не проще выставить верный ?

Comment: Если есть ссылки на примеры,скиньте пожалуйста.

Comment: какие ещё примеры ? В любом мануале первое действие настройка тулчейна ! Вы серьезно этот вопрос задаёте? Может проще сначала погуглить типа - set qt library version или qtcreator set qt version? Зачем Вам Альт линукс я спрашивать не буду....

Comment: Вам в помощь команда *ldd*, а также LD_LIBRARY_PATH, и не стоит портить системные файлы.